# Getting unhealthy containers messages during Sitecore 10 installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sitecore

I'm trying to install Sitecore 10 using docker containers locally but I'm getting unhealthy containers error messages

[image: Sitecore 10 installation]

Tried to restart docker mutilple times and re-run docker-composer again but no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that SQl container is nagging about not strong password. So I updated env file by putting a strong password and then ran these lines on PowerShell to restart docker

```
Stop-Service docker
Stop-service hns
Start-service hns
Start-Service docker
docker network prune
```

Moreover, IIS should be stopped before running docker-compose

```
docker-compose up --detach
```